# Mounting a partition into a 'sandbox'

Tags: partition, mount

I'm wondering if this is possible. I want to set up a linux system that mounts `/` remote linux machine to `/` on the local machine. However, I want all changes on the local machine to be saved to ram so that it doesn't affect the remote machine. Ideally the changes would NEVER be written, so that when I reboot, it mounts the original `/` partition again disregarding all changes made during the previous session.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: I haven't gotten around to test any of your guys' answers so It's hard to pick 1 to select as a solution. So I'll just upvote you all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) [unionfs](http://unionfs.filesystems.org/), [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) (both are  external patches for kernel) or [unionfsfuse](http://podgorny.cz/unionfs-fuse)/[funionfs](http://funionfs.apiou.org/) (uses FUSE) and create union by marking external / as RO and internal filesystem (mounted as tmpfs/ramfs/additional partition which is cleaned each time).

Alternativly you can use filesystem or LVM with snapshots. Then changes are written but you can clean snapshots at each boot.

Comment: or one could make use of the [seeding feature of btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#Seed_Device_support) (pointed out at <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs#cite_ref-16>) -- to seed a read-write fs with a read-only base. If the base fs is btrfs...

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to go about this. The easiest set up would use a union filesystem, which presents a single view of two directory trees A and B, such that all changes are saved to B. In your case, A would be an NFS/Samba/sshfs/… mount point, and B would be an initially empty directory on a tmpfs filesystem.

Linux doesn't have an in-kernel union filesystem, but there are several [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) implementations: [funionfs](http://funionfs.apiou.org/), [Unionfs-fuse](http://podgorny.cz/moin/UnionFsFuse).

Answer (score 3):

If / fits into the RAM of the local machine and leaves enough room for running applications, the basic idea would probably be to boot a minimal Linux system on the target machine and then automatically create a ramfs virtual disk, copy / from remote into it and chroot into this new /. If RAM is not sufficient, you can basically follow the same procedure but not using ramfs but a real disk partition whose content you have to clear before copying. Instead of clearing and full copy you could also use rsync with appropriate options.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for `Btrfs` and it's Copy-on-Write (CoW) feature.

The one you might be looking for is described on [Btrfs Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org) as [Seed-device](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Seed-device):

- https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Seed-device

Basic idea is to make partition with original data read-only, than to "add additional layer on a top of it", which is another writeable partition (you can always make it in RAM, e.g. on `/dev/shm`) and mount it:

```
btrfstune -S 1 /dev/RO #make it read-only
mount /dev/RO /mnt/temp
btrfs device add /dev/RW /mnt/temp
umount /mnt/temp
```

and from that moment, each time you mount

```
mount /dev/RW /mnt/test
```

changes are saved on /dev/RW, while /dev/RO stays untouched.

(examples are based on those in [wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Seed-device) )

Answer (score 0):

This can be archiev very easy with PXE boot. i am running a live xbmc system over pxe tftp nfs boot. changes are written with COW to NFS share.